# What should the return type be?

Tags: objective-c, ios, abaddressbook, abrecord, abrecordref

```
ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonAddressProperty);
```

thisPerson is ABRecordRef

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonAddressProperty) class]);
```

And that should tell you what class is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the return type is `CFTypeRef`

Answer (score 0):

The iOS documentation says: CFTypeRef - or do I get you wrong?

Regards
Chris